# No perf (linux-tools) for kernel 4.5.2

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, battery

When I first installed 16.04 LTS, at kernel 4.4.0, I had a decent battery life of about 3 hours average, but I upgraded to 4.5.2 to solve the suspend problem and some other issues, and now it's less than 1.40 hours, even at low brightness.

Then, comparing the TLP outputs of the two kernels, I noticed that at 4.5.2, sudo tlp stat said:

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/min_perf_pct      = 18
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct      = 100
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo          = 0

x86_energy_perf_policy: program for your kernel not installed
```

When I try to install linux-tools, as explained at TLP's troubleshooting website, which says

```
tlp-stat -p shows "x86_energy_perf_policy: program [for your kernel] not installed."

Depending on the distro your mileage may vary:

Ubuntu: install the meta-package linux-tools (or linux-tools-lts-* for HWE stack kernels), no package available for mainline kernels.
```

I get:

```
Package linux-tools is a virtual package provided by:
      linux-tools-virtual 4.4.0.21.22
      linux-tools-lowlatency 4.4.0.21.22
      linux-tools-generic 4.4.0.21.22
    You should explicitly select one to install.
```

So no tools for 4.5.2 kernel., i.e. no perf. Installing sudo apt-get install linux-tools-generic, just offers 4.4.0* kernel tools.

Is perf related to battery life and can I install it somehow to kernel 4.5.2?

Using Lenovo z51-70, i5, AMD and Intel graphics on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.